# mysql how to remove a record

Tags: mysql

I know NOTHING about mysql so please bear with me.

I use something called livesite for my website app and it creates these things called forms when anyone can post on my site. I didn't know about he forms when I setup the site and now I have 75000 spam forms submitted. I still don't know how people (or robots more likely) are doing it, must be a back door somewhere.

Livesite only allows you to delete one form entry at a time which will obviously not work for me.

I know the back end is mysql but my ISP will not help because its not their problem.

Can someone please give me the absolute idiots guide to deleting a bunch of records in mysql. All the records look like this on the livesite management page:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to find about [mysql how to remove a record](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+how+to+remove+a+record)?

Comment: How do you know the forms you want to delete? by the `ReferenceCode` column or what?

Comment: I see a button Add advanced filters , may be there is something there